# Is it possible to use a local GeoTIFF file as background layer in plotly.express scatter_mapbox

Tags: mapbox, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I am using the plotly.express scatter_mapbox() function to visualize points on a map. What I would like to add is a raster layer of a flood extent directly from a local GeoTIFF file.

In the example below, I have added a raster through a WMTS service.

```
gdf = gpd.read_file(asset_path, layer='kast')
gdf = gdf.to_crs('EPSG:4326')
    
fig = px.scatter_mapbox(gdf, lat=gdf.geometry.y, lon=gdf.geometry.x, color='waterdepth_48hr')
    
fig.update_mapboxes(
            accesstoken=mapbox_token,
            layers=[{
                'below': 'traces',
                'sourcetype': 'raster',
                'source': ['https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/tiles/service/wmts/brtachtergrondkaart/EPSG:3857/{z}/{x}/{y}.png']
            }],
            style='white-bg'
)
```

This is the result

[image: WMTS background layer]

Instead of a WMTS url, I would like to use a local .tif file as input. How can I do this?

Comment: seems like a lot of work to do this https://towardsdatascience.com/displaying-a-gridded-dataset-on-a-web-based-map-ad6bbe90247f